# Why does this condition in a while loop get executed as though it were part of the loop body?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, conditional-statements

Here's the relevant function (this example is taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx)):

```
​function factorial (num) {
  if (num < 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (num == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
var tmp = num; 
  while (num-- > 2) {
    tmp = tmp * num;
  }
return tmp;
}
console.log(factorial(8));
----> 40320
```

As I was studying how this function works (and got stumped on the operator precedence in the expression `(num-- > 2)`; kudos to my mentor Edwin Calte at MakerSquare for pointing that out), I noticed that the `num` variable decrements even though this decrementation is something that is stipulated as a precondition for the loop body to be executed and is not itself part of the loop body. I could understand why it would do that if the expression read instead like:

```
while (num-- > 2) {
num--;
...}
```

In the above example, that second `num--` isn't necessary for it to work. Another similar expression where this *doesn't* seem to happen when I run it in my devtools console is:

​`if (x - 2 == 5) { x-- }`

Here, it seems that if x is 7 then x will decrement by 1, ​**not**​ that if x is 7 then 2 will be subtracted from x, and then x will decrement by 1. But in the above example with ​`num`​, the latter principle is what takes effect.

Could someone please explain why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)

Comment: num-- changes the value of num

Comment: Just keep in mind that there's nothing special about the parenthesis in an if/for/while statement.  It gets evaluated just the same as code that is in the loop body. The condition succeeds if the value returned by the parenthesized expression is truthy. Even assignments are expressions: `x = 1` will return the value `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every time the expression `num--` is evaluated (which it is on every iteration of the loop to see if the condition is met) it is decreasing `num` by one. A lot of JavaScript gurus will tell you to avoid `num--`, `num++`, `--num`, `++num` exactly because of their not-so-intuitive side effects.

My advice would be to stick with things that are more readable at first glance, even if it is a few more characters to type.

```
while (num > 2) {
  num = num - 1;
}
```

At the very least, only use them as standalone statements to make what they are doing clear.

```
while (num > 2) {
  num--;
}
```

In your second example with the expression `x - 2 == 5`, this expression does not operate on `x` at all; it doesn't change it's value. You're not assigning anything back to `x` like you are when you do `x--`. `x--;` is exactly equivalent to `x = x - 1;`. It just so happens that it also returns the value of `x` *before* the assignment is made; this way it can be used as the conditional. It's like reading from a variable and then writing to it all in one statement.

Comment: Your latter point is true, but I don't think that discounts intuitive readability.

Comment: They're perfectly readable when used in standalone statements. They have the potential to be confusing when embedded as part of other expressions.

Comment: It's true, but this is all subjective and irrelevant to the answer anyway. It's my opinion, and that of many of my colleagues, that those operators are just cruft, even as standalone statements. Regardless, it was clearly confusing OP.

Comment: @Codorilla That's not what I'm talking about. I'm saying that no one considers the `i++` in `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` unreadable. But `x++ < 2` can be confusing because you're combining incrementing with comparison. Or C-style `*p++ = x`. Some of these become idioms, but they're still confusing until you get used to them.

Comment: I suppose it's just a quirk of the decrement/increment operators then? I'll take your advice when writing code. But I had to ask for whenever it pops up when I'm reading other people's code as in the above example. Thanks.

Comment: It's not really a "quirk", so much as it's just how they are designed to work. They were implemented to "save time" but the fact that this conversation happens over and over again kind of proves how much that's not actually the case :P I would honestly prefer it if the language just omitted them. But yes, it's still best to understand what they are and what they do :)

Answer (score 1):

`num--` does two things: it subtracts `1` from the variable `num` (assigning the result back to `num`) and also returns the original value of the `num` to be used in the rest of the enumpression. So

```
(num-- > 2)
```

is short for:

```
(temp = num; num = num - 1; temp > 2)
```

Your while loop could be written as:

```
while (num > 2) {
    num--;
    tmp = tmp * num;
}
```

Notice that I no longer have `num--` in the `while` clause. If I did, the variable would get decremented twice: once while testing the condition, and again inside the loop.

Comment: What's interesting is it's not *quite* the same thing. If `num` is initialized to `5`, In your second example `num` is actually equal to `2` whereas in the original example it's equal to `1` because you decrement before you compare and, in the last case, you decrement when `num == 2` before determining that it's not less than `2`. Functionally in this case it doesn't matter a bit, but it's a nice potential gotcha!

Comment: Good point. It doesn't matter in the given program because it doesn't use `num` after the loop, so its final value is irrelevant. But it could in some other program.

Answer (score 0):

`x - 2` would express a new value, ie if you opened the console and typed `x - 2` it would respond with `5`, but that value is not assigned to anything (and thus `x` is unaffected). The `--` and `++` operators are self-contained statements which affect the variable on which they are operating. So your `num-- > 2` is the name as saying `num > 2` followed by a `num = num - 1`, which compares the current value, then performs a mathematical operation and assigns the result of that operation to the variable.

Comment: Your equivalence is not correct. `num--` decrements the variable, but returns the OLD value, not the new one.

Comment: Don't you know the difference between `x--` and `--x`?

Comment: Yes, I just never use them in a case where that matters so I mixed them up.

Comment: See what I mean by non-intuitive? :P